# Printing out list elements issue

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that prints out items from a linked list. It is printing out things fine, but once it reaches the end and hits a node that was I think null or with no initial number, it prints out a random number (I'm guessing stored in the computer). How can I fix this?

```
void printList(intNode*& intList)
{
intNode* current;

if (intList==NULL)
{
    cout << "No elements to print-list is empty." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Elements in list:" << endl;
    current = intList;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        cout << current->intValue <<endl;
        current=current->nextNode;
    }
    if (current==NULL)
    {
        cout << "End of list" << endl;
    }
}
}
```

Here is where I create the list:

```
 void createList(intNode*& intList)
 {
  intNode* lastInt; //points to last integer in file
  lastInt = NULL;
  int fileInt; //int read from input file

ifstream intInputFile;
intNode* anotherInt;
anotherInt = new intNode;

intInputFile.open("intInput.txt");
if (intInputFile.is_open())
{
    cout << "intInput.txt open successful" << endl;
    cout << "check" <<endl;
    while(intInputFile>>fileInt)
    {
        if(intList==NULL)
        {
            intList = anotherInt;
            lastInt = anotherInt;
            lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
            lastInt->nextNode = new intNode;
        }
        else
        {
            lastInt = lastInt->nextNode;
            lastInt->nextNode = NULL;
            lastInt->nextNode = new intNode;
        }
        lastInt->intValue = fileInt;
        cout << lastInt->intValue <<endl;
    }
    lastInt->nextNode->nextNode=NULL;
    intInputFile.close();
    cout << "List created from input file" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "intInput.txt open unsuccessful" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: this code looks fine at a glance, maybe the bug is where you set the list up

Comment: c++ doesn't initaize so if you aren't setting the value it will be random.

Comment: The list-walking looks fine.  You should show us your code that populates the list.

Comment: @paddy I have added it to my original post.

Comment: @AA how is intNode defined?

Comment: @billz It's a struct that contains an integer and a pointer nextNode that points to an instance of intNode

Comment: 'struct intNode
{
    int intValue;
    intNode* nextNode;
};'

Comment: @billz Check my previous comment.

Comment: @AA try Doug T's code, it should work

Answer (score 0):

If you do not initialise your ints, when you access them you cannot be sure of what they will return. I would suggest initialising all your ints and if it is still happening do as Karthik commented and check how your list is initialised.

Comment: By ints, do you mean integers?

Comment: Yes. As in, whatever data structure you are using to hold the numbers in your linked list. Whatever they are, they should be initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things in the wrong order.  You create your new node in `lastInt->nextNode` but then you assign the value to `lastInt->intValue`.  That means you'll always have a node at the end of the list which has not been initialised.

The whole thing looks rather convoluted.  How about this:

```
intNode * intList = NULL;
intNode * lastInt = NULL;

while( intInputFile>>fileInt )
{
    // Initialise a new node.
    intNode *newNode = new intNode;
    newNode->nextNode = NULL;
    newNode->intValue = fileInt;

    // Append to list.
    if( intList == NULL ) {
        intList = newNode;
    } else {
        lastInt->nextNode = newNode;
    }
    lastInt = newNode;

    // Make noise...        
    cout << newNode->intValue <<endl;
}
```

There's other options for populating lists, including not setting the 'NULL' until you finish the loop (all intermediate ones are redundant), or using a dummy head node.  But let's just keep it simple.

Notice that I used a temporary variable inside the loop to make it very clear which node I was assigning data to.